# Ошибка c отношением многие ко многим Django

Tags: python, django

**Выдает аткую ошибку,как можно исправить это?**

> MultipleObjectsReturned at /events/sub/1/ get() returned more than one
>   Event -- it returned 2!

**views**

```
def cards_detail (request,pk):
    # if pk:
    event_detail = Event.objects.get(pk=pk)
    subs = event_detail.subs.count()

    # else:
    #     return CardsView()
    args = {'event_detail':event_detail,'subs':subs}
    return render(request,'events/cards_detail.html',args)


class CardsView (TemplateView):
    template_name = 'events/cards.html'

    def get (self,request):
        events = Event.objects.all()
        return render(request,self.template_name,{'events':events })

def subs_to_event (request,pk):
    event = Event.objects.get(pk=pk)
    Event.make_sub(request.user,event)`
```

**models**

```
class Event (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateField(default='')
    dicript = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Описание отсутствует')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    adress = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name="creator",null=True)
    subs = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='subs',blank=True)

    @classmethod
    def make_sub(cls, this_user, sub_event):
        event, created = cls.objects.get_or_create(
            user=this_user
        )
        sub_event.subs.add(this_user)
```

**urls**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',HomeView.as_view(),name = 'home'),
    url(r'^cards/$',CardsView.as_view(),name = 'cards'),
    url(r'^cards/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',views.cards_detail,name = 'cards_with_pk'),
    url(r'^sub/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',views.subs_to_event,name = 'subs_to_event'),
 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

В `django` `get` должен возвращать [ровно один объект](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get). Если объектов [больше одного](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/exceptions/#multipleobjectsreturned) или вообще не нашлось, то будет порождаться исключение.
В вашем случае под условия `get` подходят два объекта. О чём и символизирует ошибка. 
Если вы хотите взять все объекты, которые удовлетворяют данному условию, то используйте [`filter()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.filter).

Comment: то есть мне нужно в def subs_to_event использовать filter?